# Прекращена работа программы "Python" (модуль pygame)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Не запускается модуль Pygame, несколько раз переустановил питон для того, чтобы модуль заработал, но ничего не помогает, причем происходит это только с этим модулем, все остальные работают нормально. Раньше pygame работал нормально, сейчас нет.

**(Файл крашится даже просто оттого, что я импортирую модуль)**

```
import pygame
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо за помощь!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается папка с модулем была повреждена, я удалил ее и переустановил заново, все работает